# Do I need to check out my luggage if I exit the airport during transit?

Tags: transit, luggage

I'm traveling to USA and I'm seeing a few flights that have long layovers. For eg : 10h in AUH or 17h in LHR. I was considering exiting the airport with a transit visa. But do I have to check out my luggage and check it back in?
It is definitely not worth it if I have to check it out as travelling with a lot of luggage is a hassle.

Comment: We left the airport in Qatar without any problems. Bags were checked through, no one in customs or immigration blinked an eye. The Gulf carriers are primarily transit airlines, Long layovers at odd hours are quite common and it's very normal to head into town if you have extra time (and the right Visa/Passport)

Comment: That sounds unlikely, and can you Post more detail about what you mean by "exit the airport during transit"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin during the transit period, instead of waiting in the airport, I thought I could exit the airport and come back in time. During this process, wanted to check if I will be asked to check out the luggage since I'm leaving the airport.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general (there are exceptions), with two international flights, if both flights are on the same ticket, and you have a layover/connection/stop (as opposed to a stopover which is usually >24 hours), your luggage will be checked through to your final destination, so when you land at the connecting airport, your luggage will be transferred to the next flight and you won’t see it. You usually wouldn’t be able to get your checked luggage even if you wanted to.

If you exit the airport, the airline most probably won’t even know anything about it. As long as you are back at the gate for your departing flight in time, they don’t care.

As long as you have the appropriate documentation (passport, visa…) there shouldn’t be a problem at immigration. They are actually probably happy that you have luggage that is still in the system, as that makes it even more likely you will actually leave as planned.

Customs might be intrigued by the fact that you don’t have any luggage, especially in places where most of the traffic is long-haul. But that should be cleared up pretty quickly.

One important thing, though: when you do your initial check-in at the fist airport, you will usually get the boarding pass for the two flights. In some cases they cannot give you the second boarding pass at that time (often when the first flight is very long and the layover very long as well), and you have to get it at the connecting airport (usually from a “transfer desk”). Make sure you get that boarding pass before you go through passport control. It may be trickier to get it after that, and you won’t be able to go through security and to your gate without that.

As I wrote at the beginning, there ARE exceptions where things work differently, like with transits in the US and a few other places, so you may need to specify exactly which airports and flights are involved.

Also, things are completely different if the flights are on separate tickets. Some sites (especially the infamous Kiwi) sell “connecting” flights which are ticketed separately, so beware.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica if the two flights are on the same ticket there is nearly certainly an interlining agreement, and AFAIK in both LHR and AUH such flight combinations will result in luggage being transferred without being seen by the passenger.

Comment: I've even done this intentionally -- booked a ticket that would have had a two hour connection and extended that to 26 hours by selecting the same flight number one day later for the second leg. This works best with airlines that permit check-in on the previous day, while budget airlines might get confused.

Comment: very nice answer

Comment: @SimonRichter how did you update it intentionally? how were you able to update only the second leg of the journey?

Comment: @akshayub, I booked it this way -- travel agents can build tickets like this in Amadeus, but it requires a few extra steps because it's not in the search results.

Comment: @akshayub I did something similar as Simon Richter except in my case I moved the first leg forward. I did this by calling Finnair's customer service after having booked the full flight online (online search did not allow me to add the 24 hour layover I wanted). I had to pay the difference in fares which was something like 10 € so both the agent and I chuckled on the phone.

Comment: Always check your baggage tags to make sure your bags are checked all the way through to your final destination. This will give you good confidence your bags won't be left behind along the way, even if you have a long layover. Be especially vigilant if checkin agents are sharing a bag-tag printer, as tags can get shuffled, and once mis-tagged bags are hard to locate. It took eight days just to find my wife's bag that went to St Louis instead of Singapore.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the country, but generally not. As originally written, your question is unclear about *when* you “check out [your] luggage and check it back in”.

If you’re talking about retrieving your checked bag(s), leaving the airport with your bags, then returning for your next flight and re-checking your bag(s), then no. You’ll never have to do this that I’m aware. If you mean will you have to retrieve your bags, then recheck them before you leave the airport during your layover, returning later for your flight, then probably not. Your bags should be checked to your final destination.

But there are exceptions…

I’ve had layovers at JNB, coming from outside South Africa and merely stopping over while enroute to another African country, where I had to retrieve my checked bag(s), exit security, and recheck them with the airline before proceeding. As someone else has already said, this is a requirement in the US. You indicated the US *is* your final destination, but you’re not asking about doing this in the US. You asked about doing it while at another international intermediate stop in another country before arriving into the US. I’ve never had to do this at any airport anywhere in the world *except* JNB.

Comment: Correction: you have to do this in the US if you arrive from abroad, whether your final destination is in the US or not. There are a few rare exceptions.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks; I edited my answer.

Comment: @jcarson The first flight the OP mentioned is one of those "rare exceptions"...

Comment: @Doc: How so ? AUH is presumably an Etihad flight and Etihad will definitely check the bags through.

Comment: @Hilmar My comment was specifically directed at jcarson and his comment that you need to collect bags on arrival in the US.  This is NOT the case when coming from AUH (US Preclearance)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, and last time I went through a connecting airport in the USA I moved from air- to groundside several times with no question from airport security, immigration or anyone else.

By the third time I went out for a smoke, the security people were showing not only recognition, but sympathy for the fact that I had to take off my steel-toed boots to get through their scanners. (Hint: Do not wear steel-toed boots for air travel!)

Looking back I clearly did exit the airport and move into - what shall we call it? US ground-space?

Had I tried to take luggage with me, the result might have been different and I doubt that. I do believe that's a question of practicality, not law.

In transit, how could any of us check out any baggage?

Comment: The OP is asking about transit in AUH or LHR neither of which is in the US so your experience there is not of direct help to them.